# Array of observables into Observable of Array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this piece of code where I need to change an array of `Observable`s into an `Observable` of array:

```
 this.output = this.firsProvider.getIds(uid)  // return array of Ids : String[]
     .flatMap(obs$ => obs$)  
     .map((id: string) => this.secondProvider.getOneItem(id) // return an Observable of Item
     );
```

#### Objective

I want to merge all Observable of item into one big observable of all items. My code only return output: `Observable < Observable < Item>>`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be looking at using a syntax like this. You can get request the items in parallel and wait until all complete using [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) on the array of individual observables. This code will start with `String[]` and result in an `Observable<Item[]>`.

```js
const itemObservables = this.firstProvider.getIds(uid)
    .map(id => this.secondProvider.getOneItem(id));

this.output = Observable.forkJoin(itemObservables);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will return an observable containing an array of items:

```
 const itemsArray$ = this.firstProvider.getIds(uid)
   // return array of observable item
  .map(idArray => this.secondProvider.getOneItem(id)),
  .mergeMap(observableItemArray => {
      // zip will return an array of items
      return Observable.zip(observableItemArray)
  });
```

Afterwards, if you want a stream of items, use the from observable, like this:

```
const items$ = itemsArray$.mergeMap(itemArray => {
    return Observable.from(itemArray);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator. Look this function typing with `combineLatest`.

```
function t$ArrayToTArray$<T>(ts$:Observable<T>[]):Observable<T[]>{
  return Observable.combineLatest(ts$);
}
```

Its first array emits only when every observables has emitted at least once.